# Linq-to-SQL Database Update Fails

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

Very simple update. It simply fails, no error, no change gets made to the database.

```
Dim db As New BarClassesDataContext
Dim foo = (From a In db.articles Where a.id = 14 Select a).Single
Response.Write("<h3>" & foo.title & "</h3>")
foo.title = "This is my new, updated title for article ID #14"
db.SubmitChanges()
```

Here is the relevent portion of my article class. Also, this is a web form so I have no console. Is there another way to view the T-SQL output?

```
<Table(Name:="dbo.article")>  _
Partial Public Class article

    Private _id As Integer
    Private _issueid As Integer
    Private _dateadded As Date
    Private _title As String
    Private _titlelink As String
    Private _description As String
    Private _image As String
    Private _imagelink As String
    Private _type As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New
    End Sub

    <Column(Storage:="_id", AutoSync:=AutoSync.Always, DbType:="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsDbGenerated:=true)>  _
    Public Property id() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._id
        End Get
        Set
            If ((Me._id = value)  _
                        = false) Then
                Me._id = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
```

Comment: Are you sure there's an id that equals 14?

Comment: Yes, there is and id that equals 14.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any invalid fields definitions you may have an issue where 0=1 is added to the `WHERE` clause.  Check that all of your non-nullable fields are set.  (I fought with this for about two hours one night while watching the SQL profiler add the extra 0=1 for *no* reason.)

- [Post on Social MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/eb3900b4-79e5-469d-9582-e5428353d86c/)
- [Another post about this issue](http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2008/04/28/6139181.aspx)

(If I can find the issue on [connect.microsoft.com](http://connect.microsoft.com/) I will post it as well)

Comment: Good thought!  As I mentioned in my answer, setting the `.Log` property will give you the SQL being executed so you should see right away whether you have something funky happening instead of guessing/debugging.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I would say one (but not the main) problem is '='. I think it needs to be:

```
Dim foo = (From a In db.articles Where a.id == 14 Select a).Single
```

The main problem I see is the lack of an UpdatetOnSubmit() statement. How does L2S know you want to do an Update?

Try

```
db.Articles.UpdateOnSubmit(foo);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

or something close to this.

Comment: There is no such thing as `==` in VB.NET.  It sanely knows when to use `=` for assignment vs `=` for equality comparisons.  C# knows how to do this too, but it just gives you a compiler error when you use the wrong one.

Comment: There's also no such thing as `UpdateOnSubmit()`.  There's `InsertOnSubmit()`, but that's for new records only.  The DataContext tracks which objects it gave you and will update them just with a call to SubmitChanges().  C'mon... C# code for a VB question and made-up methods - you've got a really nice rep score so I have to assume that you really do know better than this.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that you don't have a properly defined primary key in your database and/or in your System.Data.Linq.Mapping attributes.  Show us the `Article` class - that will likely be where your problem is.  Make sure you have an IDENTITY field in your database, and be sure your linqed up class has got IsPrimaryKey:=True and IsDbGenerated:=True in the `<Column>` attribute.

Also, it would be wise to set the .Log property on your DataContext to see what SQL is being executed.  I like the debug window logger technique, which I have mentioned before here: [DataContext SubmitChanges in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295703/datacontext-submitchanges-in-linq/3295750#3295750)